# How to work out overlap of the union of date intervals in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, given a table of date intervals, how can I find the overlap of their union with a single date interval of interest?

For example, given a table of date intervals (call this table A) as:

```
         start_date     end_date

         2021-02-01   2021-05-01    
         2021-04-01   2021-07-01  
         2020-12-01   2021-03-01 
         2021-09-01   2021-12-01
```

And the single date interval of interest (call this table B) as:

```
         start_date     end_date

         2021-01-01   2021-11-01
```

I would like to calculate the overlap between the intervals in A with the interval in B **as 8 months**.

When A's intervals are disjoint, I can solve this with the following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(GREATEST(0, DATE_DIFF(LEAST(B.end_date, A.end_date), 
                              GREATEST(B.start_date,A.start_date), MONTH))) 
    AS months_overlap
FROM 
    A, B
```

The problem comes in when the date intervals in A overlap with each other, as in the above example, in which case the above code double counts overlapping intervals in A i.e. it will return **10 months** for the above example.

Any suggestions on how to calculate the overlap of these intervals without double counting? I thought about introducing Lags into the date diff function but I'm not coming right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select count(1) as months_overlap
from (
  select distinct date_trunc(day, month) month
  from tableA, unnest(generate_date_array(start_date, end_date - 1)) day
)
join (
  select distinct date_trunc(day, month) month
  from tableB, unnest(generate_date_array(start_date, end_date - 1)) day
)
using(month)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to expand the various intervals into months, join and count:

```
with b as (
      select mon
      from b cross join
           unnest(generate_date_array(b.start_date, b.end_date, interval 1 month)) mon
     ),
     a as (
      select mon
      from a cross join
           unnest(generate_date_array(a.start_date, a.end_date, interval 1 month)) mon
     )
select count(distinct mon)
from a join
     b
     using (mon);
```